# Utility function that generates a demand curve which will have an U shaped MR curve

Tags: microeconomics

This is based off an [answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/24834/19094) given by @Ubiquitous in here: [Can marginal revenue be increasing?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24833/can-marginal-revenue-be-increasing/24834?noredirect=1#comment39250_24834)

The solution he proposed involved a MR curve that sloped down, then up and then down. His equation for the demand curve (for example) to generate such a MR is $P(q)=1−q+3q^2−3q^3$ (see comments below his answer).

My question is:

Is there an Utility function that can generate a demand curve which gives, say an U-shape looking MR?

Note: I am not looking for an utility function that replicates Ubiquitous's MR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v(x) = \int  1 − x + 3x^2 − 3x^3 \text{d}x$.
The quasi linear utility function
$$
U(x,y) = v(x) + y
$$
generates the [inverse demand curve given by Ubiquitous](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/24834/1601) if income $I$ is large enough and $p_y = 1$, as
\begin{align*}
|MRS(x,y)| & = p_x \\
\\
v'(x) & = p_x \\
\\
1 − x + 3x^2 − 3x^3 & = p_x.
\end{align*}
Hence it will also result in the same $MR$ for $x$.

P.s.: I have not checked if $U(x,y)$ is convex, so second order conditions may need to be examined here. Note that $U(x,y)$ need not be convex everywhere, only above the $MR$'s U shape. Everywhere else it can be altered as we see fit.

Comment: @ Denesp: Thank you for your answer. Based on my calculations for the interval (0,8), if $Q = \frac{32}{16-p}$  then $P = 16 - \frac{32}{Q}$. This means that revenue is $PQ = 16Q-32$, implying MR = 16, a constant. So MR is not U shaped here, yes?

Comment: You are indeed correct. My guess is that going from constant do increasing would not be very difficult, by tweaking the utility function a bit, but I forgot that you want to have a U shape, not an upside down U shape.

Comment: @erik I edited my answer.

Comment: @ denesp: Your solution is very nice. I feel like I should have thought of it. And your function does not have any convexity issues. I will post a picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the utility function @denesp gave in his answer above. It does not have any convexity issues in the range $0<x<0.3$, which is the range where the MR will have an U shape.

The function:

[image]